# Codeigniter .htaccess in godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am struggling with this for hours now:
I have a codeigniter application in a **sub folder** in a godaddy hosting, lets say:

```
mydomain.com/myfolder/myapp/
```

I have this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /myfolder/myapp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I read this doc: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips
but it won't help neither. Maybe because my ci app is in a subfolder?

How can I hide the index.php? and make it work with friendly urls?

Comment: I'd just suggest you try different hosting when your current plan expires, because GoDaddy greatly sucks. Source: Own experience

Comment: well thanx but that is not a solution. I cannot say that to my customer :P
just edited the question, in case someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `/myfolder/myapp/.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /myfolder/myapp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

then in `/myfolder/myapp/application/config/config.php` you need to have this config:

```
$config['base_url']  = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Thanks!
Now it won't give me an error, but it always opens the welcome controller, even if I try to go to another! Do you know what is happening?

Comment: never mind! I changed the uri protocol to auto and now it works! thanks

Comment: oh ok that's great, I made it `AUTO` in my answer to help any future visitor to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Create a .htaccess file in you root directory (where codeigniter's index.php is) with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    #RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Then in your **application/config/config.php** :

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

This should solve the issue.

Comment: No, I get the following error:
Not Found

The requested URL /mydomain/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @Perroloco remove the RewriteBase line.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Had "no input specified" error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the following .htaccess for Godaddy hosting server. Please let us know if it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody wrote that you're supposed to put

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

at the beginning of your .htaccess file, for a GoDaddy hosted website.