# Remove Index.php from URL of sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello friends i have sub domain like exam.example.com, i need to remove index.php from url my url like exam.example.com/index.php/controller/func_name

i had replace following in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

replace

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and create .htaccess file in my project and wrote following code -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Check this hope it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542588/remove-php-from-url/42427045#42427045

Answer (score 0):

I also hosted one of my CodeIgniter project as a subdomain like yours. I don't face any issue like you.

I also replaced following in config.php $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; 
replace with $config['index_page'] = '';

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If this .htaccess file did not work for you need to allow overriding of htaccess in Apache Configuration.
visit [Codeigniter - getting 404 Not Found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284147/codeigniter-getting-404-not-found-error/43318913#43318913) for more information about .htaccess overriding.